# Actions During Sleepwalking

Tags: pediatrics, waking-up, technology, parenting, sleep-walking

I am a high school student doing a biomedical engineering project about sleepwalking. For my project, I am prototyping a novel healthcare solution to prevent lengthened periods of sleepwalking in children. For my prototype, the child will be wearing a wristwatch (an Apple Watch for this prototype). There will be an app installed on the prototype to detect if the child is awake and is moving a certain distance. When the child moves a certain distance, an alarm will play on the phones of the parents of the sleepwalking child. The parents can then wake up and guide their child back to bed. If this prototype is renovated and made "industry-worthy", then the child will avoid doing harm to things around the house and to themselves.

I only have one concern with my idea. Will the child be able to take off the watch while they are sleepwalking?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I was thinking... will be there a way to deactivate the alarm? In case the child want to go to the bathroom for example, if the answer is yes you should worry about that too...